# Why is this crashing in the Swift Playground?

Tags: swift

Trying to run this in the playground and get an Error Running Playground.

```
enum DBSortOrder {
    case ascending(String)
    case descending(String)
}

func keysInTableForConditions(#table:String, sortOrder:DBSortOrder?) -> [String] {
    return []
}


var keys = keysInTableForConditions(table: "tester", .descending("sequence"))
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: Looks like an Xcode bug. If you take out the String associated value, it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like a bug.for now change this line of code

`var keys = keysInTableForConditions(table: "tester", .descending("sequence"))`

with this

```
var keys = keysInTableForConditions(table: "tester", DBSortOrder.descending("sequence"))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your sortOrder is optional

change

```
sortOrder:DBSortOrder?
```

to

```
sortOrder:DBSortOrder!
```